# How to Pass Numbers in Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any option or solution to pass Numbers is Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons like

[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-use-css-to-surround-a-number-with-a-circle)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is there any option or solution to pass Numbers is Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons?

In short, no. Here are [all the available glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons).

Glyphicons either come as an image file or font set.  Either way, they are not extensible.  They are individual icons.  It's like saying, I know there's a character set of a-z, but can it also have a icon of a puppy.  Or I know this is an image of an apple, but can the pixels change so it's a number.

---

You can, of course, easily do this with CSS.  It's a trivial implementation, so I wouldn't worry about the 'cost of extra classes'.  If you're developing a website, you should have plenty of classes.

Try any of the suggestions from [how to use CSS to surround a number with a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4861224/1366033):

### Use Border Radius

```html
<div class="numberCircle">30</div>
```

```css
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

### Use Unicode Characters

For 20 and lower, you can just use the [enclosed_alphanumerics unicode characters](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/enclosed_alphanumerics.html):

```html
&#9312;
&#9313;
&#9314;
&#9315;
&#9316;
&#9317;
```

### ① ② ③ ④ ⑤ ⑥

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/esm3jssy/)

Comment: Hi KyleNit and thanks for reply. I was wondering if this is possible in Bootstrap itself so no need for extra classes

Comment: Short answer, no. Bootstrap is a framework to start with, but won't contain everything. When you've got something specific, start adding stuff like this. You'll be very lucky or end up with a very generic looking site if you only use whats built into Bootstrap.